# iOS: Using LaunchImage as app background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, swift

Is this possible without glitches?

My Xcode project has a launch image defined in the assets (aka Images.xcassets) incl. all supported sizes and orientations. Since I want to use the same image as background in my initial view, I add it in the view controller as background:

```
    view.layer.contents = UIImage(named:"LaunchImage").CGImage;
```

However when the launch screen switches to the initial view there's a noticeable glitch since the background image set in the view stretches. Also when I rotate the device, the image stretches.

The stretching occurring when the device is rotated seems plausible since obviously the other image sizes/orientations in the asset catalog image aren't regarded when set as a background image (my guess).

But the stretching that occurs between launch screen and my initial view seems rather strange since the two should have the same size.

Is there any tried and tested procedure to have the bg image always adapt with aspect ratio in mind when the device orientation changes? And is this even possible wit the (multi-sized) launch image?

---

**UPDATE:**

One possible method to add a bg image is by placing a `UIImageView` in the background (behind all other views) and load the image into it. That solution takes care of the device orientation issue and would be OK for me but there is another issue: It loads the wrong image size. If I test it on iPad2 emu it should use the image named **Default~ipad~nostatusbar.png** but if I check the size of the `UIImage` it is only 320x480 pixels so it obviously used the image named **Default.png**.

And I can only load the launch image by the name defined in the Images.xcassets. If I try to create a UIImage with physical filename (e.g. Default.png) the bg will stay black.

So the question is: How do I get iOS to choose the right image size/orientation from LaunchImage in Images.xcassets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a UIImage+DefaultImage [ios] category in objC that allows this. Should be easy to port to a swift extension

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (DefaultImage)

// uses statusbar orientation
+ (UIImage *)defaultImage;

//uses given orientation
+ (UIImage *)defaultImageForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orient;

@end
```

---

```
@implementation UIImage (DefaultImage)

+ (UIImage *)defaultImage {
    return [self defaultImageForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
}

+ (UIImage  *)defaultImageForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orient {
    // choose the correct launch image for orientation, device and scale
    NSMutableString *launchImageName = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Default"];
    BOOL isPad = ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad );
    if ( isPad ) {
        BOOL isLandscape = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orient);
        NSString *imageOrientation = (isLandscape) ? @"Landscape" : @"Portrait";

        BOOL isRetina = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0);
        NSString *scaleString = (isRetina) ? @"@2x" : @"";

        // Default-Landscape~ipad.png
        // Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
        // Default-Portrait~ipad.png
        // Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
        launchImageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@%@.png", launchImageName, imageOrientation, scaleString];       
    } else {
        if ( CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) > 480.f) {
            // Default-568h.png
            launchImageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@-568h.png", launchImageName];
        } else {
            // Default.png
            // Default@2x.png
            launchImageName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", launchImageName];
        }
    }
    return [UIImage imageNamed:launchImageName];
}

@end
```

Disclaimer: my own code -- taken from https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDUtils

Comment: But this method only assembles the image file name and generates a UIImage from it. But if I try to specify the physical file name, e.g. UIImage(named:"Default.png"), it already doesn't work. It obviously doesn't find the image by its physical file name (though it exists) but only with the asset ID, e.g. 'LaunchImage'.

Comment: Another oddity is that my launch image contains files for sizes incl. status bar and without, e.g. Default~ipad~nostatusbar.png. These however aren't regarded at all in your solution.

Comment: Grml nevermind! I just figured out that the image filenames are changed during compilation!

Comment: UIImage *myImage = [UIImage defaultImage];

Comment: there are maybe cases where I haven't covered an image :) -- I wrote that a while ago. you might extend it to cover those images but thats the way to go

Comment: It's cool now! I've wrote my own getDefaultImage method based on yours which works well. I haven't taken the statusbar option into account though as my app is iOS7+ only anyway and the statusbar is transparent on iOS7 so always the fullscreen image is used.

Answer (score 4):

To fully resolve this issue, here's my Swift version of Daij-Djan's code. It also lists the ridiculous amount of different launch image versions in the comment block. there are some calls to my own util lib (EnvUtil) but that's another story and most users can figure out how to get the needed vars.

```
/**
   Returns the default image (launch image) of the application with regard to the screen size and orientation.

   Default.png                               | LaunchImage.png                       |  320 x 480  | iPhone 4 Low Res.
   Default@2x.png                            | LaunchImage@2x.png                    |  640 x 960  | iPhone 4
   Default@2x.png                            | LaunchImage-700@2x.png                |  640 x 960  | iPhone 4 iOS7
   Default-568h@2x.png                       | LaunchImage-568h@2x.png               |  640 x 1136 | iPhone 5
   Default-568h@2x.png                       | LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png           |  640 x 1136 | iPhone 5
   Default~ipad.png                          | LaunchImage-Portrait~ipad.png         |  768 x 1004 | iPad Portrait
   Default~ipad~nostatusbar.png              | LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png     |  768 x 1024 | iPad Portrait FS
   Default~ipad~landscape.png                | LaunchImage-Landscape~ipad.png        | 1024 x 748  | iPad Landscape
   Default~ipad~landscape~nostatusbar.png    | LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png    | 1024 x 768  | iPad Landscape FS
   Default~ipad@2x.png                       | LaunchImage-Portrait@2x~ipad.png      | 1536 x 2008 | iPad Portrait Retina
   Default~ipad~nostatusbar@2x.png           | LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png  | 1536 x 2048 | iPad Portrait Retina FS
   Default~ipad~landscape@2x.png             | LaunchImage-Landscape@2x~ipad.png     | 2048 x 1496 | iPad Landscape Retina
   Default~ipad~landscape~nostatusbar@2x.png | LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png | 2048 x 1536 | iPad Landscape Retina FS
 */
public class func getDefaultImage() -> UIImage
{
    var fileName:String = "LaunchImage";
    let osVersion:String = EnvUtil.systemVersionMajor() > 6 ? "700" : "";
    let scale:String = EnvUtil.isRetina() ? "@2x" : "";
    let div:String = osVersion.length > 0 ? "-" : "";

    if (EnvUtil.isPad())
    {
        let orientation:String = EnvUtil.isPortraitOrientation() ? "Portrait" : "Landscape";
        fileName += "-" + osVersion + div + orientation + scale + "~ipad";
    }
    else
    {
        if (CGRectGetHeight(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) > 480.0)
        {
            /* iPhone 5. */
            fileName += "-" + osVersion + div + "568h@2x";
        }
        else
        {
            /* iPhone 4 with iOS7? */
            fileName += div + osVersion + scale;
        }
    }

    fileName += ".png";
    //Log.debug(fileName);

    return UIImage(named: fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The launch image is in the app bundle (named default.. ) so you simply have to load it into a UIImageView and add that imageView to your UIView.

Comment: This seems to fix the orientation stretch issue however it picks the wrong image size. When I check the size of the image on iPad emulator it says 320x480 which isn't right.